# Require defined type in hash table

Tags: puppet

I have a defined type called `profile_winsql_dbengine::resources::sqlconfighelper` which calls an exec block and works fine.

I am using the following create resource statement in my init manifest:

```
create_resources( profile_winsql_dbengine::resources::sqlconfighelper, $sqlconfighelperhash )
```

The hash is declared as follows:

```
$sqlconfighelperhash = {
    'config1' => {
      param1     => $param1,
      param2     => $param2,
    },
    'config2' => {
      param1     => $param1,
      param2     => $param2,
      require    => Profile_winsql_dbengine::Resources::Sqlconfighelper['config1'],
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected, with the exception of the `require`. The `require` throws a compilation error, telling me that it can't find `Profile_winsql_dbengine::Resources::Sqlconfighelper['config1']`

The syntax compiles, and without the `require` it applies the profile as expected. What should I do differently, to make the `require` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this using latest Puppet 5.3.4.

My code:

```
# /tmp/test.pp
define test::my_type($message, $withpath) {
  notify { $name:
    message  => $message,
    withpath => $withpath,
  }
}

class test (
) {
  $data = {
    'message1' => {
      message  => 'I am message 1',
      withpath => false,
      require  => Test::My_type['message2'],
    },
    'message2' => {
      message  => 'I am message 2',
      withpath => false,
    }
  }
  create_resources(test::my_type, $data)
}

include test
```

Then:

```
$ puppet apply /tmp/test.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.06 seconds
Notice: I am message 2
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Test::My_type[message2]/Notify[message2]/message: defined 'message' as 'I am message 2'
Notice: I am message 1
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Test::My_type[message1]/Notify[message1]/message: defined 'message' as 'I am message 1'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.05 seconds
```

Probably you have a typo somewhere maybe?